# keydown not triggering until key pressed twice

Tags: javascript, keydown

so i have a div I'm trying to toggle the class of depending on if a another div is empty or not.

currently with key down when a key is pressed nothing happens, and then when a second key is pressed the display style is switched to none.

this is the same for when text is removed in the div, when the div is empty it does not switch back to display block, but when backspace is pressed again (once already empty), then the display value is changed back to block.

Any thoughts?

HTML

```
  <div id="textbox">
    <div id="colon" class="consoleText consoleArea"><span class="consoleIcons">&#10132;</span></div>
    <div role="textbox" contenteditable="true" id="navtype" class="consoleText" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: 40px" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 37)" onpaste="return false;" spellcheck="false"></div>
    <div class="consoleText"><span id="caret"></span></div>
    <div class="placeholder">type here to change directory</div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript

```
let consoleMsg = document.getElementById("navtype");

let consoleText = document.querySelector("[contenteditable]");

consoleText.onkeydown = function () {
if (consoleText.innerText) {
    let placeholder = document.querySelector(".placeholder");
    placeholder.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    let placeholder = document.querySelector(".placeholder");
    placeholder.style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

Comment: Please include your html in a complete sample that shows the problem. What is `consoleText`?

Comment: @wazz Sorry have added html and further JS

Answer (score 1):

The issue was using .onkeydown - what I should of used was .oninput -

.onkeydown seems to have a delay the function is fired before the input is added.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(consoleText.innerHTML !== null || consoleText.innerHTML !== "" || consoleText.innerHTML !== undefined) {
   let placeholder = document.querySelector(".placeholder");
   placeholder.style.display = "block";
} else {
  let placeholder = document.querySelector(".placeholder");
  placeholder.style.display = "none";
}
```

The best way to check content of a DIV is innerHTML. Your code should listen to triggeringElement.innerHTML instead of keydown event. If the input element is  go for  triggeringElement.value.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I tried implementing this, it seems that now the function doesn't work at all. weird. I've added html and further JS if that helps.